# inline-block last-child element issue

Tags: vertical-alignment, css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble positioning last-child of inline-block horizontal scrolling site. In firefox everything looks ok, but in Chrome last child of articles is somehow pushed down, for about 18px. Of course, I've tried to separately assign the "vertical-align:top" to last element, but still no {good} result ...

Here's my site: http://rup.fiser.biz/braunova/category/scenography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.post {
  height: 351px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

remove `float: left;` as you have `display: inline-block` (`float` or `display`, can't have both as far as I know)

```
.site-content article {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

and remove `margin` if you want to move the las element next to others

Comment: `float` or `display` > here you go :) `[REC CSS 2.1]` [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)